# Как закрепить положение формы?

Tags: c#, winforms, position

Необходимо чтобы при старте программы окно появлялось в левом нижнем углу, и при это его нельзя было передвинуть. Заранее всем большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3):

[Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907830/how-do-you-prevent-a-windows-from-being-moved) из английской версии вопроса. И код перегрузки соответствующего метода с небольшим дополнением, чтобы окно появилось в левом нижнем углу:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
{
    //Эта строка установит положение формы в левом нижнем углу
    this.SetDesktopLocation(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Left, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Bottom - this.Height);

    //этот код предотвратит возможность перемещения формы на экране
    const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    const int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;

    switch(message.Msg)
    {
        case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
           int command = message.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
           if (command == SC_MOVE)
              return;
           break;
    }

    base.WndProc(ref message);
}
```

Этот код нужно добавить в код формы, которую хотите закрепить.

**UPD:**

В `this.SetDesktopLocation(int x, int y)` в принципе, можете передать любые координаты, которые можете рассчитать удобным для Вас способом с привязкой к размеру экрана и размеру формы.

Чтобы меню "Пуск" не перекрывало нижнюю часть формы, можете заменить

```
this.SetDesktopLocation(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Left, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Bottom - this.Height);
```

на

```
var wArea = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this);
this.Location = new Point(wArea.Left, wArea.Bottom - this.Size.Height);
```

Comment: а как задать начальную позицию формы в левом нижнем углу?

Comment: Обновил ответ..

Comment: Все отлично! Но можно ли выводить его сразу над меню "Пуск"? А не прямо от самого низа)

Comment: Да, от второго параметра, который передаёте в `SetDesktopLocation`, нужно отнять высоту меню "Пуск".

Comment: Огромное спасибо!